# Python: How to fit the arbitrary shapes to ploygons and find all the vertex and segments

Tags: python, image-processing, line, vertex

I am trying to find all the closed regions in an image, fit the arbitrary shapes to polygons, and then extract all the vertex and corresponding segments. I am very fresh to image processing, so I don't know if there is any existing function/library/algorithm I could use. I have searched a lot on google, and most suggestions seem to use 'line detection + Hough transform' to find the vertex. I have tried above method using the code below, but the results are not satisfying. The 1st image is original one, and the red line in the 2nd image is detected segments. We can see the algorithm miss some lines, and can't form closed loops either. I have tried to tune the parameters in HoughLinesP functions, results could be improved, but still can not show complete closed loops. 
[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovYtO.png) [Hough lines on original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Vp0.png)

Also, the image is just an example, and actual image I am working is more complex (shape is more arbitrary, and the size of each region varies a lot). So, in a short summary, what I need help is:

1, convert the arbitrary shape to polygons (I need them to be polygons for further use.)

2, extract all the vertex and corresponding segments.

I would really appreciate if anybody could shed light on this.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import image as image

I = image.imread('test.jpg')                 # read image
G = cv2.cvtColor(I, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)      # convert 3D matrix to 2D

# Canny Edge Detection:
Threshold1 = 100;
Threshold2 = 100;
FilterSize = 5
E = cv2.Canny(G, Threshold1, Threshold2, FilterSize)

# Hough line transform
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(E,rho = 1,theta = 0.1*np.pi/180,threshold = 1, 
minLineLength = 1, maxLineGap = 1)

# Plot the hough line in original image    
N = lines.shape[0]
for i in range(N):
    x1 = lines[i][0][0]
    y1 = lines[i][0][1]
    x2 = lines[i][0][2]
    y2 = lines[i][0][3]
    cv2.line(I,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),2)

plt.figure(),plt.imshow(I),plt.title('Hough Lines'),plt.axis('off')
```

Comment: I don't think you fully understand what you are doing here. how did you chose the parameters you're using?

Comment: @Piglet You are right, I am very fresh in image processing, I am not quite sure how each parameter works even looking at the definition. I tried a few sets of parameters to run (for example, maxLineGap ranging from 1 to 10 etc.). It seems the smaller parameters, the better for mine case. But I just can't find the right fit no matter how I adjust the parameters.I hope somebody could help to point out if HoughLinesP is the best approach for my case, before I put much effort in figuring out the meaning of each parameter. find the right fit no matter how I adjust the parameters.

Comment: first fo all you should think about how many points you want to have in a polygon. if you're using a line length of 1 you could as well just use the points without doing any calculations...

Comment: @Piglet may I know what's the purpose to get how many points in the polygon? I can find all the cells in each colored regions using flood fill approach. But don't know what's next. Just don't have the big picture in my mind.